# ASP.NET Validation server side

Tags: asp.net, validation, client-side, server-side

I have an ASP.NET webform which I want to validate Client-Side and Server-Side, using the same validation controls.
I can't seem to find the solution for this - the client validation works great, but when I disable javascript - It ignores the validation.

Help would much be appreciated.

Roman

Comment: can you give us more info? Specifically what validation controls are you using? The built-in ASP.NET validators? If so then which, of these, are you using (e.g. CustomValidator). Some snippets of pertinant code always help. Finally, are you using update panels or anything AJAX-y?

Comment: Using the regular validators, no CustomValidator at all.
Nothing AJAXy, no panels ... nothing. just a plain form :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always trigger validation by the `validator1.Validate()` method, which will do the server-side comparison.  Check `Page.IsValid` to see if server-side validation isn't being performed?  I think you can invoke it via `Page.Validate()`.

HTH

Answer (score 15):

Explicitly call [Page.Validate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ke7bxeh.aspx) on the server side.

Or the overloaded [Page.Validate(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.validate.aspx) to target one of your validation groups.

**Update:**

I forgot, after you run Validate(..), check the [`Page.IsValid` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid.aspx) - it's up to you to stop the page from submitting if this property `== false`.

Comment: Hi,
I've tried this - But still didn't work.
I use the regular asp.net validators. even not the custom one.

when I disable javascript - it just goes through, even if I explicitly use Page.Validate();

Comment: Hmmmmm ... if you haven't already, try the overloaded version.
Otherwise, which method or event are you calling Page.Validate from?

Comment: I missed the boat on that one by forgetting about Page.IsValid.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using standard validation controls, data is always re-verified on the server even if client side validation is specified.

See the note in this article right after figure 2:, which says:

> Double-Checking Client-Side Validation
>
> One interesting point is that even
> though the form data is validated on
> the client (eliminating the need for
> additional requests to and responses
> from the server to validate the data),
> the data entered is re-verified on the
> server. After the data is checked on
> the client and found valid, it is
> rechecked on the server using the same
> validation rules. These are rules that
> you establish to ensure against some
> tricky programmer out there trying to
> bypass the validation process by
> posting the page to the server as if
> it passed validation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx

However, you can force validation on the server by calling Page.Validate()

Answer (score 3):

Roman,

You can use the ASP.net custom validator to provide both a client and a server method for validation. That way if you disable the js you should still hit the server validation method. In this example the "ClientValidate" function would be defined in a javascript block on your page, and teh "ServerValidate" function would exist in your codebehind file.

```
<asp:textbox id="textbox1" runat="server">
<asp:CustomValidator id="valCustom" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="textbox1"
    ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate"
    OnServerValidate="ServerValidate"
    ErrorMessage="*This box is not valid" dispaly="dynamic">*
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: All ASP.NET Validators provide client and server side validation - not just the CustomValidator.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!
The answer is to use Page.Validate() and then check for Page.IsValid to check if the validation was valid or not.
Only using Page.Validate() didn't help - the code proceeded and didn't stop.

Thanks guys,
Roman